# Issues adding a date to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm taking a date in a CSV and trying to add it to my database in mysql date format. Here's my code (or some of it):

```
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
 {
    $originalDate = $data[1];
    echo "original date format:".$originalDate."<br/>";

    //$delivery_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($originalDate));

    $parts = explode('/', $originalDate);
    $delivery_date = $parts[2] . '-' . $parts[1] . '-' . $parts[0]; // 09/12/2011

    echo "new date format:".$delivery_date."<br/>";

    $row++;
    $import="INSERT into dispatch (delivery_note_number, delivery_date) 
    values ('$data[0]','$delivery_date')";
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());

 }
```

The 'echos' are just to help me debug. The new date format $delivery_date echoes in a way that should be suitable to stick into the database e.g. 2012-04-15

However, when I check the database, all I end up with is 0000-00-00

Any ideas why mysql won't take the date?

Comment: note I've tried strtotime to convert the format, and explode, just to see if it made any difference. It hasn't.

Comment: Check your $import (echo it to see what is wrong). Your $delivery_date variable may be seen as "$delivery_date" in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to :

```
$import="INSERT into dispatch (delivery_note_number, delivery_date) 
    values ('".$data[0]."','".$delivery_date."')";
```

That should help.